# Correct date formatting for a Google Calendar Event

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to create an event for Google Calendar and I'm getting this error :

```
Invalid value for: "T" found, can only parse bare date string: 2013-08-22T16:00:00
```

I also tried adding the timezone offset to my string but I set the timezone manually in the EventDateTime object and according to the documentation it's not neccesary.

Here is how I create my time string :

```
data['start'] = $("#inputDateStart").val() + "T" + $("#inputTimeStart").val();
```

And how I set this string in my object

```
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setTimeZone('America/Montreal');
$start->setDateTime($data['start']);
$event->setStart($start);
```

What am I missing? All day events work fine when I just set my date using the setDate function.

Answer (score 5):

I dont know your whole code, but I was getting the same error message when trying to set a date-time on a Google calendar event. When I used the Google online api checker, the date/time format and timezone I was using worked just fine. In the end I found that the problem was because I had done this (using something similar to your notation):

```
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDate('2013-10-10');
$event->setStart($start);
```

And then later after finding I had both date and time data available:

```
$start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
$start->setDateTime('2013-10-10T19:15:00');
$event->setStart($start);
```

This gave me the error message you mention. Maybe the Google parser thought it was a day event only and then was confused by additional date/time data.
The problem went away when I checked first if I had both date and time data and just did:

```
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
$start->setDateTime('2013-10-10T19:15:00');
$event->setStart($start);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply append the timezone at the end of the time:

```
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00');
$event->setStart($start);
```

This is GMT-7

So in your case this would work:

```
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime($data['start']."-4:00");
$event->setStart($start);
```

:)

Though googles own documentation is old and invalid, you may like to use some of their methods: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert